# How to use maven sonar scanner to include javascript files as well?

Tags: maven, gitlab, sonarqube, gitlab-ci, cicd

My maven project repo structure

- ui-modules
- modules
- modules/accounts
- modules/notification
- modules/users

I'm able to configure and run sonar-scanner in gitlab using below

```
 SONAR SCAN:
  image: maven:3.8-openjdk-11
  stage: build  
  script:
    - cd modules
    - mvn clean install
    - mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.qualitygate.wait=true -Dsonar.projectKey=<KEY> -Dsonar.host.url=<HOST_URL> -Dsonar.login=<LOGIN>
```

Since my javascript files were not detected by above:

I've tried this configuration

```
SONAR SCAN:
  image: sonarsource/sonar-scanner-cli:latest
  stage: build
  script:
    - apk add maven
    - cd modules
    - mvn package -DskipTests=true
    - cd ..
    - sonar-scanner -Dsonar.qualitygate.wait=true -Dsonar.projectKey=<> -Dsonar.java.binaries=modules/ -Dsonar.sources=ui-modules/ -Dsonar.host.url=<> -Dsonar.login=<>
```

But above configuration is not detecting java files.
How to configure single job for running scan on ui-modules folder as well as modules folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set all directories which you would like to scan via [sonar.sources](https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/latest/analyzing-source-code/analysis-parameters/#analysis-scope) variable:
 `-Dsonar.sources=./ui-modules,./modules`